# Sql SUM points step by step

Tags: sql, sum

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID_points ID_team points date
1         1        2     1/15/2012
2         1        0     1/16/2012
3         1        -1    1/17/2012
4         1        3     1/18/2012
5         1        4     1/18/2012
```

Now, what I want to do is to SUM the points, but not ALL the points, rather step by step so I can have a nice chart.

For example I would like my table to look like this (after I filter the team by ID, and order by date ASC):

```
ID_points ID_team points date
1         1        2     1/15/2012
2         1        2     1/16/2012
3         1        1    1/17/2012
4         1        4     1/18/2012
5         1        8     1/18/2012
```

Is this possible or not?

Comment: What RDBMS? And it's also a duplicate of assorted "Running Total" questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bsql+%2B+running+%2Btotal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @tbl table (ID_points int primary key, ID_team int, points int, [date] date)

insert into @tbl select 1,1,2,'1/15/2012'
union select 2,1,0,'1/16/2012'
union select 3,1,-1,'1/17/2012'
union select 4,1,3,'1/18/2012'
union select 5,1,4,'1/18/2012'


select t1.ID_points, t1.ID_team, sum(t2.points) points, t1.[date]
from @tbl t1
left join @tbl t2
    on t1.ID_points >= t2.ID_points
group by t1.ID_points, t1.ID_team, t1.[date]
```

Comment: if you could help it will be really great, because I don't have any idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DBMS that supports windowing functions, it's as simple as:

```
SELECT ID_points, 
       ID_team, 
       points, 
       sum(points) over (partition by id_team order by date) as running_poins
FROM the_table
ORDER BY id_team, date
```